# The loop is supposed to create 10 paragraphs and insert text, but the text only appears in one

Tags: javascript, for-loop, dom

In firebug console 10 paragraphs is displayed in the source code of the page, but only the first one contains text.

It looks like the loop inserted the text each time into the same paragraph, overwriting it's value. How to insert the text into each paragraph?

```
(function(){

    var names = ["Yaakov", "John", "Jen", "Jason", "Paul", 
        "Frank", "Larry", "Paula", "Laura", "Jim"];
    for (var name in names) {
        var new_par = document.createElement("p");
        new_par.id = "new_par"; 
        var greeter = document.getElementById("greeter");
        greeter.appendChild(new_par);

        var firstChar = names[name].charAt(0).toLowerCase();

        if (firstChar === 'j') {
            //byeSpeaker.speak(names[name]);
            document.getElementById("new_par").innerHTML = "Goodbye" + " " + names[name];


        } else {
            //helloSpeaker.speak(names[name]);
            document.getElementById("new_par").innerHTML = "Hello" + " " + names[name];           
    }
    }

})();
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Module 4 Solution Starter</title>

</head>
<body>
  <h1>Module 4 Solution Starter</h1>
  <div id="greeter"></div>

  <script src="SpeakHello.js"></script>
  <script src="SpeakGoodBye.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can’t use the same ID multiple tmes. Simply use `new_par` instead of `document.getElementById("new_par")`. You don’t need IDs at all.

Comment: @david it is explained, it could be clearer tough... I've added the little bit that was missing in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that each paragraph has the same id. I added a `counter` variable, to add at the end of id...

```
(function(){
    var counter = 0;
    var names = ["Yaakov", "John", "Jen", "Jason", "Paul", 
        "Frank", "Larry", "Paula", "Laura", "Jim"];
    for (var name in names) {

        var new_par = document.createElement("p");
        var par_id = "new_par" + counter;
        new_par.id = par_id; 
        var greeter = document.getElementById("greeter");
        greeter.appendChild(new_par);

        var firstChar = names[name].charAt(0).toLowerCase();

        if (firstChar === 'j') {
            //byeSpeaker.speak(names[name]);
            document.getElementById(par_id).innerHTML = "Goodbye" + " " + names[name];

        } else {
            //helloSpeaker.speak(names[name]);
            document.getElementById(par_id).innerHTML = "Hello" + " " + names[name];         
    }
    counter++;
    }

})();
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are creating ten nodes with the same id, new_par, so you are always getting a reference to the first #new_par when you do

```
 document.getElementById("new_par").innerHTML
```

The simplest solution will be to use the reference you already have, no need to call getElementById.

```
new_par.innerHTML = ...
```